# printing results in multiple lines in python facing an error

Tags: python, endl

In C++, we simply use `std::endl` in order to print a result in multiple lines. How can I do the same in Python? I use '\n' and I face a problem.

If I wanted to write the code in C++, here's how I'd write it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
   int a,b;
   cin>>a>>b;
   cout<<a+b<<endl<<a*b<<endl<<pow(a,b)<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `sep` keyword:

```
num1 = int(input())
num2 = int(input())

print(num1+num2,num1 * num2,num1**num2, sep='\n')
```

or simply `comma` seperate them:

```
print(num1+num2, '\n', num1 * num2, '\n', num1**num2)
```

In python `+` between `str` and `int` are not allowed, you could use `f-strings` if you are running python 3.6+:

```
print(f"{num1 + num2}\n{num1 * num2}\n{num1**num2}")
```

Comment: or you do `str(num1+num2) + "\n"` etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
#you can use the following format also
print('{}\n{}\n{}\n'.format(num1+num2, num1*num2, num1**num2))
```